# “This phone number already exists on your account” error in Facebook

Tags: facebook

I broke my phone and relied on Facebook to contact my friends. Unfortunately, I forgot my password, reset it and was locked out for 24 hrs. During that time, I created another profile so I could communicate. Now it won’t let me log in because it says this number already exists on your account. I tried multiple times and was again blocked. What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same " duplicate phone number" issue as well. I solved it by clicking "Forgot Password", then search for my account, and clicked "I don't have access to these" and I provided a new email address and new password. They sent a verification email to my new email address, I clicked into the Facebook verification link in my email to verify my account.

After 24 hours, I can log in using my new email address and new password. After that, I chose the new email address as my username to log in in future. Other email address (including old email address and the phone number) were removed.

This is how I solved my problem. It really works. I tried to look for Facebook help centre but there is no reply from them and they never publish this solution in their site. Do help to spread this and help others too.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. I solved it by saying I needed to change my password, then said I didn't have access to my email and provided a new cell phone number to use. This allowed me to change the password. 24 hours later I was able to log in. On log in, I was asked what user ID wanted to use. I selected my email address clicked OK then Facebook automatically deleted my original cell phone number and the alternate I used.

Answer (score 0):

From the Help Page:

[I can't sign up because there is already another account associated with my phone number.](https://www.facebook.com/help/158461840955940)

> If you've signed up for Facebook with your phone number in the past but you can't remember your password, you can [reset your password](https://www.facebook.com/recover/initiate) and log into your account.
>
> If you haven't signed up with your phone number before, make sure you've typed your phone number correctly. If you've typed your phone number correctly and see a message that an account already exists with your number, [**let us know**](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/439851082721667).

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't signed up with your phone number before, make sure you've typed your phone number correctly. If you've typed your phone number correctly and see a message that an account already exists with your number